# AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, browser, attributeerror

hi guys I hope that you are having a great time.
so I'm having this problem when I'm tring to execute this script.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


url = "https://www.google.com/"


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
#Change chrome driver path accordingly
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path = r"C: \drivers\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options =chrome_options)
print (driver.title)
```

the results in cmd:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\modaw\Desktop\firefox elo\hi.py", line 12, in <module>
        opts.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', 'localhost:9222')
    AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the same problem try using this string with code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

opt=Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:8989")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=opt)
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below with Firefox:

> AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'

Because to deal with the website certificate problem, I used `add_experimental_option()` which `FirefoxOptions()` doesn't have as shown below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']) # Error
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/")
```

So instead, I used `accept_untrusted_certs` as shown below, then I could solve the problem:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.accept_untrusted_certs = True # Here
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/")
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the third line to `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options` instead of `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import options` since the `Options` class is uppercase. Otherwise Python will not import it successfully.

Python names are case-sensitive.

[Chrome WebDriver Options Methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium_webdriver/selenium_webdriver_chrome_webdriver_options.htm)

Comment: I try but its not working "from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import options" the options module is disabled and it cause errors

Comment: Can you try again after changing it to `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.Options` otherwise it does not find the `Options` module

Comment: same results do you have a discord or something please I'm really freaking out with script

Comment: Where are you defining `opts` in your code? You're defining it as the correct subclass that has `add_experimental_option` right?

Comment: thnx man i found the problem i should do it like this 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

opt=Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:8989")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=opt)
driver.get("http://google.com")

Comment: thnx man i found the problem i should do it like this 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

opt=Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:8989")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=opt)
driver.get("http://google.com")